# Unity3D - iOS 16 unknown sound playing when Game open

Tags: c#, iphone, unity-game-engine, audio, ios16

I have recently been experiencing an issue in one of my games that runs on an iOS 16 device. When my Apple ID is not logged in and I open the game, an unknown sound plays. However, when I log in to my Apple ID on the device and then open the game, the sound disappears.

The error returned when playing the sound is:

> Blockquote
> 0x12f08c9a0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit Media Playback' for process with PID=3,815, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}

I can't find any solution. Please help me with this. Thanks